# How to pause mplayer whenever I switch to another window?

Tags: mplayer

I'm using [mplayer](http://mplayerhq.hu/)-gui and would like to have it pause whenever I switch to another window and playback when I switch back.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: @iglvzx it's in fluxbox under FreeBSD